# phpmyadmin, how to replace a character in all tables?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to replace a character, let's say all "a" should be replaced by "b", in all rows in all tables of my database.

Is there a way to do this in phpmyadmin?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using **[`Replace()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)** function, example

```
UPDATE tableName
SET colName = Replace(colName, 'a', 'b')
```

by the way, `replace` is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks Sorry one more thing, I actually need to replace an apostrophe ’ with another one '. What's the exact syntax in this case ?

Comment: @Patrick try it doubling the `replace`. `Replace(Replace(colName, 'a', 'b'), '\'', 'x')`